# Problem Mathematica/Windows frontend: cell evaluation

Tags: notebooks

Using Mathematica actual I have problems executing or activating notebook cells:

Every input  needs an extra click on the mousepad to evaluate!

Any idea how to "repair" Mathematica? Thanks!